# Linear Algebra question relating to eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, statistical-inference, eigenfunctions

Let A be an m x m positive definite symmetric matrix with eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs

$(\lambda_1,e_1),....,(\lambda_m,e_m).$ The eigenvectors are orthonormal.

Let $C = e_1e_1'+....+e_me_m'$.

Find $Ce_j$, $j=1$, ..., $m$. Also, for $x \in R^m$, find $x - Cx$.

i) $Ce_j = e_1e_1e_j+....+e_me_m'e_j$.

ii) $x - Cx = (x-e_1e_1'x+....+x-e_me_m'x)$

Not sure if I'm heading in the right direction or not.

Comment: Be careful with rows vs columns, and the order (and consistency) of operations (matrices don't conmute).

Comment: Ah ok, I don't know why I did that in both parts. Will update.

Comment: "... a set of eigenvectors" of what? Of a general matrix? Or a symmetric (hermitian) matrix? Or are you told that the eigenvectors are LI or orthogonal or something? As stated, the problem seems incomplete.

Comment: The only information about C is given in the problem. $(e_1,...,e_m)$ are the eigenvectors of matrix A, an m x m positive-definite symmetric matrix.

Comment: You should add this to the problem statement, then. Furthermore: to say that they are "_the_ eigenvectors" makes little sense. One can pick different set of eigenvectors, LI or not, normalized or not. I guess that $e_i$ are a set of orthonormal eigenvectors. But, again, this should be stated.

Comment: I revised to question so that it has all the necessary and correct information. There is no more information to provide.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that
$$
Ce_j=e_j
$$
for all $j$, and hence $C$ is the identity matrix.